# retrieve image from mysql database to array php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, arraylist, popupwindow

By compiling this, display three image get my database and show it, when i click each image popup window show last image of my database.I want to know how to display the particular image, when i click first image,then popup window show first image and description, as well as same way second and third image. check to array loop in this code...

```
enter code here
<?php
            $sql=mysql_query("select * from product_reg")or die(mysql_error());
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
            {
                $productname=$row['productname'];
                $productid=$row['productid'];
                $description=$row['description'];
                $image=$row['image'];


                $firstN = array();
                $i=0;
                $firstN = '<img src="'.$row ['image'].'">';
                echo '  <a href="#" class="big-link" data-reveal-id="myModal" name="image" style="float:left;margin:100px 0 100px 100px;"> ' ;  echo $productname;echo $firstN[$i];
                $r=$firstN[$i];
                echo '</a>';
                $i++;

            }

    ?>


        <div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal">
        <form>
        <table>
        <tr><td><?php   echo $r; ?></td>
            <td><h1>Reveal Modal Goodness</h1>
            <p>This is a default modal in all its glory, but any of the styles here can easily be changed in the CSS.</p></td>
            <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: how to pass the value from php code to div id="myModel".iwant to pass particular image value

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have the images stored in the database like BLOB data. If so you need to create a handler to retrieve those images and render them as image/[mime]...

So in short.

In your code you need to create a new file iz get_image.php in it you need to make a request to the server and retrieve the image so you can send it to the client.

In your code you need to change the image path to the handler path with some query parameters.

```
 $firstN = '<img src="get_image.php?imageid='.$row ['productid'].'">';
```

There are a lot information how to render the image to the client from the internet.

Answer (score 0):

may be you have to declare your `$firstN = array();` and then incrementor `$i=0;` out of while loop and put in array like this:

```
$firstN[$i] = '<img src="'.$row['image'].'">';
```

below is the full code:

```
<?php
      $sql=mysql_query("select * from product_reg")or die(mysql_error());
      $firstN = array();
      $i=0;
      while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
      {
         $productname=$row['productname'];
         $productid=$row['productid'];
         $description=$row['description'];
         $image=$row['image'];
                
         $firstN[$i] = '<img src="'.$row['image'].'">';
         echo '<a href="#" class="big-link" data-reveal-id="myModal" name="image" style="float:left;margin:100px 0 100px 100px;"> ';  
         echo $productname;
         echo $firstN[$i];
         $r=$firstN[$i];
         echo '</a>';
         $i++;
      }
?>
```

---

#### Updates:

You have a space here:

```
$firstN[$i] = '<img src="'.$row['image'].'">';
//-----------------------------^----here at this code block;
```

Comment: ok.now it will sho the image, but issue not clear..when while loop complete $r store only last image,thats why, popup window show last image, when i click any image...

Comment: yes because `$r` is in loop so it gets updated every time your loops updates. so if it loops 3 times then 3rd one gets set in it.

Comment: how to pass the value from php code to div id="myModel".iwant to pass particular image value

Answer (score 0):

To get the last image , you need to modify your query to have SORT BY productid DESC

To display the images

```
       echo "<a href='xxx.php?imgid=$image'><img  src='yourimagesfolderpath/$image.jpg'>    </a>";
```

to navigate in the images , you have to use JQUERY

Comment: to retrieve image from my database.in above code, when while loop complete $r store only last image,thats why, popup window show last image, when i click any image.